# Node-webkit with orm

Tags: javascript, orm, node-webkit

I'm working on desktop application using node-webkit. I would like to use database in my application. I know that I can use WebSQL and probably also Sqlite, but I would like to add some orm to simplify my work. I tried with sequelize but I have some problems with it. Do you know any examples for node-webkit + any orm library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node-WebKit you can you use modules written totally in JavaScript. For modules containing C/C++ you should build the addons by **[node-gyp](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Using-Node-modules#3rd-party-modules-with-cc-addons)** because the ABI (application binary interface) of node-webkit differs from Node's ABI.

Try smth like **[sequelize-sqlite](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-sqlite)** that **JavaScript 100%** or find other modules in npm go to it GitHub repository and under row **commits, branch, releases & contributor** click coloured row "Show language statistic".

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try it. Right now I found nedb [link](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) which is javascript object database. By default it support node-webkit, so I think it is very good choice and works also very well.

Comment: @cotampanie Wow, MongoDB like SQLite - go play with it.